# Magento - How can I use a 5 column layout on the home page and then use a 4 column layout on the category pages?

Tags: php, css, magento

I am wanting to show 5 cloumns of products on my Magento home page while showing 4 columns in the category area - Is this possible or is it a set parameter across the platform?

Answer (score 0):

Make a special layout for you homepage.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/6119/